# Define Iterator type of template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In function below, how to tell the compiler that Iterator is the iterator of Cont ?

```
template<typename Cont, typename Pred>
Iterator<Cont> find_if(const Cont &c, Pred p)
{
    return std::find_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c), p);
}
```

Comment: [std::experimental::ranges::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename Cont, typename Pred>
auto find_if(const Cont &c, Pred p)
-> decltype(std::begin(c)) // HERE
{
    return std::find_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c), p);
}
```

Or since version C++14:

```
template<typename Cont, typename Pred>
auto find_if(const Cont &c, Pred p) //All you need is auto
{
    return std::find_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c), p);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's simple. When you say in newer version of C++ do you mean at least C++14 ?

Comment: @artm: I think so? I haven't done much C++ in the last ten years, so I'm a little fuzzy on which features were added which years